# How Do I save my team site as a template inside SharePoint 2013 Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, publishing-site, team-sites

[image]

[image]

Hello this my team site, However when I go in Site Setting and Site Action it doesn't give me the option to save it as a template. I would like to know what I need to do save it as a template.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs in a case of you have activated the `publishing feature` in your team site.
And once the publishing feature is activated, you can't save site as a template and this option becomes unavailable.

**Note:** unfortunately, deactivate the feature back will not solve the issue. it is still unsupported to create a template from a site that has ever had publishing features enabled.

For more details check ["Save site as template" option isn't available in SharePoint Online in Office 365 or SharePoint Server 2013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2492356/-save-site-as-template-option-isn-t-available-in-sharepoint-online-in-office-365-or-sharepoint-server-2013)

**How to overcome this issue?**
As I mentioned above, you can't create a template from a site that has ever had publishing features enabled and all available workarounds are not supported and often not worked.Please have a look at ["Save site as template" option and the publishing feature](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature/)

So the solution will depend on your plan from the beginning you should decide which template should you use based on your requirements.

so I suggested if you need to use `save as template` with `publishing feature` you should plan from beginning to do the following:

- Create your team site.
- Finalize first all the customization that you need in your team site without enabling`publishing feature`.
- Save the site as a template and consider it this the **Master template**.
- You can now create sites from this **Master template** as you need. Meanwhile, you can enable the publishing features on the sites that created from this master team site template.
- In a case of you need to continue customization, you could do that for a site created from Master Template that not has a publishing feature enabled. then save it again as a new **Master Template** version.

For more details check [Missing save site as template in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Comment: What would I need to do ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no solution for this. Meanwhile, your site looks like a test site, so it's suggested to don't enable publishing feature until finalizing all customization that you need in your team site then save it as a template. this template should be now the master template that has customization without publishing feature enabled so you can create a new site from it. then as you need enable the publishing features for the sites that you have created from this master team site template.

Comment: @M.Qassas, have a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/06/13/save-sharepoint-2013-publishing-site-as-a-template/)

Comment: Thanks @GintasK for your feedback, but it's not supported and not working, should you have a look at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature/